# Magento 2 observer is not triggering

Tags: magento2, event-observer, frontend

We are going to use `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_before`  frontend event in M2.
please note same event which is working on M1 but it is not working please review my below code and share your ideas

app/code/Demo/Stackexchange/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_before">
        <observer name="Demo_check_for_vision_user_session" instance="Demo\Stackexchange\Observer\CheckForStackexchangeUserSession" />
    </event>
</config>
```

app/code/Demo/Stackexchange/Observer/CheckForStackexchangeUserSession.php

```
<?php
namespace Demo\Stackexchange\Observer;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;
/**
 * Class CheckForStackexchangeUserSession
 * @package Demo\Stackexchange\Observer
 */
class CheckForStackexchangeUserSession implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var SessionManagerInterface
     */
    private $coreSession;

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;  

    /**
     * constructor
     */
    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        SessionManagerInterface $coreSession
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->coreSession = $coreSession;
    }

    /**
     * Vision redirects a customer
     *
     * @param Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {

       $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP.'/var/log/magento2.log');
       $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
       $logger->addWriter($writer);
       $logger->info("Usage for");

    }


}
```

Comment: You can try with put `events.xml` to directly into etc folder

Comment: what is exact version you are using ?

Comment: what you want to achieve using this event?

Comment: AFAIK there no event `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_before` in magento 2!

Comment: I am using magento2.3.1 CE

Answer (score 2):

The name of the event is "**layout_generate_blocks_before**".

You may refer the following file to check for the event.

> vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php

There is this below function in the file that executes the observer.

```
protected function generateLayoutBlocks()
{
    $this->beforeGenerateBlock();

    Profiler::start('LAYOUT');
    /* dispatch event for adding xml layout elements */
    $this->eventManager->dispatch(
        'layout_generate_blocks_before',
        ['full_action_name' => $this->request->getFullActionName(), 'layout' => $this->layout]
    );
    Profiler::start('layout_generate_blocks');

    /* generate blocks from xml layout */
    $this->layout->generateElements();

    Profiler::stop('layout_generate_blocks');
    $this->eventManager->dispatch(
        'layout_generate_blocks_after',
        ['full_action_name' => $this->request->getFullActionName(), 'layout' => $this->layout]
    );
    Profiler::stop('LAYOUT');

    $this->afterGenerateBlock();

    return $this;
}
```

With above function, you can also get hints of arguments passed in observer that may be useful to you.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this event `controller_action_layout_render_before`
controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_before event doesn't exist

Comment: this is not triggering.